# Typescript not recognizing properties on the parent class?

Tags: typescript

I have a basic inheritence like so:

```
export abstract class Animal
{
     constructor() {

     }

     makeSound() {
         alert(this.sound);
     }
}

export class Dog extends Animal
{
     public sound: string = "Woof!";

     constructor() {
         super();
     }
}

const dog = new Dog;
dog.makeSound(); // Woof!
```

I'm having an issue trying to get the above snippet working. `Property prop does not exist on type Animal`. However, it does exist on Dog, and since it is public, Animal should be able to reach prop via `this.prop`.

I tried the following:

- Same as above - It doesn't compile. (Property prop does not exist on type Animal)
- If I add `public prop: any;` to `Animal`, then `prop` becomes `undefined` and not `Hello world`.
- If I add `public abstract prop: any;` to `Animal`, same thing happens.

The whole point of inheritence by using abstract classes is to share `this` scope.

How can I do it properly with Typescript?

Comment: No, it is top down. An apple (B) is a fruit (A) but a fruit is no apple.
Inheritance adds or changes behaviour. Your B adds a property to A. So it is clear that A does not have it.

Comment: @chris Care to elaborate?

Comment: You're assuming that any instance of A is also an instance of B. That's not true: `class C extends A {}` defines a class that extends A, and doesn't have any prop property.

Comment: @JBNizet I've been using abstract classes for like years on other languages, even vanilla JS interprets this properly. Could you explain the problem a bit detailed for me? I'm not sure where `C` comes from, or what difference it makes. The whole point of abstract classes is to get a class to extend it...

Comment: Every language I know of will also refuse to compile that. When the compiler compiles A, it can't find any property `prop` in A, nor in any of its superclasses. The fact that there is a subclass of A that defines such a property is irrelevant: nothing guarantees to the compiler that all subclasses of A have a `prop` property.

Comment: @JBNizet Updated the snippet for clarity. Can't I tell compiler that I know what I am doing, and this property will be available? Like `public reference sound` or something? So compiler knows there is a `sound` property defined on the extended class?

Comment: Why don't you instead define it in the superclass, if it's supposed to exist for all instances of this superclass?

Comment: @JBNizet sound property should exist in all classes, but each animal makes a different sound so each animal type (e.g Dog) should define their own sounds. I'm not sure if we can't understand eachother, but the snippet above works on all scripting languages like PHP, JS and alike. Could you give me a jsfiddle example about defining it in a superclass?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with JB Nizet. But you also have the ability to define `sound` as an abstract property. That way your base class knows about `sound`, and all extending classes have to implement the abstract property `sound`:

```
export abstract class Animal
{
    abstract sound: string; // Only change here, now your code works
    constructor() {

    }

    makeSound() {
        alert(this.sound);
    }
}

export class Dog extends Animal {
    public sound: string = "Woof!";

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const dog = new Dog;
dog.makeSound(); // Woof!
```

The ability to define abstract properties came with TS 2.0: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4669

**Update**

The problem OP experienced with this approach, see comments, was that the abstract property was used in the constructor of the abstract base class. This will not work since the property is assigned the initial value from the deriving class first *after* the object is instantiated.

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9230) for this problem, where the solution is to simply error on access to abstract properties within the constructor of the abstract class.

Comment: Alex, when I tried using the abstract keyword approach, sound was `undefined` so it didn't read the value from the extending class, as I mentioned on my question. I'll give this one another try and let you know shortly. Edit: Yeah, when I do `console.log(this.sound)`, it outputs `undefined`. I am on Typescript `2.1.4`.

Comment: @IcarusCocksson works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wRwff7MrFazrjYQHKmFI?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet @Alex Weird, it doesn't work for me. I pushed the commit into my repository if you want to have a look: https://github.com/Aristona/Phaser.Adventure-Capitalist/tree/master/src/Shop - This is the abstract class and line 50-55 is where I define the abstract properties. All the classes in the Shops folder extend the Shop and define those properties themself. When I run it, all of them becomes `undefined`. (everything between line 50 and 55 in Shop.ts). Any ideas?

Comment: @IcarusCocksson I had to remove those exports when running your example code in [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) for it to work so I guess it has something to do with that. I'll take a look at your repo.

Comment: I tried removing them myself, Typescript complains about not having exported members. Thanks alot for the help. My repo can be a bit messy as I was converting my little game into Typescript to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: @Aris Have you debugged your code, so that you are sure that this is not just a coding error somewhere? Unfortunately I'm currently not able to pull in your repo and build it myself.

Comment: @Alex I'm not exactly sure what could be wrong. I guess those `export` declarations may be problematic. I'll change my typescript and gulp settings and dig until I find the cause. Thanks alot for the help. Your example works properly (actually, that's what I did initially) but I guess it is the exports that was breaking my code. Selecting this one as the answer.

Comment: @Aris Well, of course you should be able to export stuff... Problem was mostly that I just couldn't past it in directly in playground and have it working as it was, so I was thinking that you were maybe trying something similar. If you find something interesting, please keep us updated if there is a language bug somewhere.

Comment: @Alex Hey Alex, I tried to solve it. Seems like it occurs when I try to access `this.sound` in the abstract classes constructor. `makeSound() {         alert(this.sound); }` works, while  `constructor() { alert(this.sound); }` alerts `undefined`. Usually, abstract classes has to construct themself with data coming from the parent class. I don't want to pass everything to `super()` as parameters...

Comment: @Aris Ah, I see. If you look at the compiled javascript, you can see that TypeScript instantiates the inheritance chain first, and *then* assigns the properties to the derived class. I'm not sure about this, you might report this to the typescript github and see what they say. Maybe there should be an error message if you reference abstract properties in the constructor of the abstract class.

Comment: @Aris Check out these links: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9209, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9230

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you should define your two classes:

```
export abstract class Animal {

  protected constructor(public sound: string) {
  }

  makeSound() {
    alert(this.sound);
  }
}

export class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super('woof');
  }
}
```

Putting the property in the Animal class tells the compiler that all animals have a sound. Putting the sound as an argument of the superclass constructor makes it clear that all subclasses must specify their sound when constructing the instance.

There are other possible variations, but if the superclass needs to access the sound property or some getSound() method, then this property/method should exist in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is exactly right: `prop` does not exist on `A`, because it exists on `B`. You might be coming from JavaScript, where what you did is just fine. The key difference between TypeScript and JavaScript is that TypeScript s strongly typed and JavaScript is weakly typed. That difference requires a change in your thinking.

In a weakly typed language like JavaScript, it simply doesn't matter that `prop` does not exist in `A`. Types are resolved at runtime and if your actual instance has `prop`, everything will be fine. In a statically (or strongly) typed language, things are different. Types are enforced at compile time and if `A` doesn't define `prop`, it can not use it. That's why strongly typed languages allow you to define abstract members: to make them accessible at base classes, but to actually define rhem in derived classes.

Since [not all versions of TypeScript support abstract properties directly](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4669), this solution should work in any case:

```
export abstract class Animal
{
    get sound(): string { return getSound(); }
    protected abstract getSound(): string;
    constructor() {}
    makeSound(): void {
        console.log(this.sound);
    }
}

export class Dog extends Animal
{
    protected getSound: string { return "Woof!"; }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const b = new B;
B.makeSound();
```

Comment: Is get/set syntax mandatory? Also, the following syntax looks a bit weird. `protected getProp: string { return "Hello world"; }`. Why do we define type as string but place an object literal with a return keyword? o_O

Comment: @IcarusCocksson: `getProp` is a method, not a property. The get syntax with the method call is because at least early versions of TypeScript don't support abstract properties. Hence using a getter and calling an abstract method.